# Which is the most secure method of creating a cryptographically unique token in PHP

Tags: php, yii, cryptography, token

I have this working I would just like some advice on the most secure option of creating a token (for an API) and would either of them have any issues going forward?

Option A:

```
$token = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16));
```

or Option B:

```
// $username - unique username for this user
$token = hash('sha512', sha1($username.time().rand(1000, 9999)));
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the relative strengths of different cryptographic approaches. There is no programming question here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the question is off-topic, it's interesting.

My answer: Option A.

Option B contains at least one predictable value, $username.  The `time()` value might be predictable, and `rand()` is predictable if the seed can be guessed.

Have a look at this: https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

Edited to add: Of course, if the token does not have to be kept secret, it doesn't make any difference.  You could just use the user name.